# Linq To Sql: handle NewID()

Tags: linq-to-sql, default-value

hey, im trying to add data to my sqlserver by using Linq To Sql,
in the table, the data design to get NEWID() when new row is inserted,
but the linq to sql ignore it and the cell in null,

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're expecting a guid value to be auto-generated for you right at the time of insert. It sounds like that column has a `DEFAULT` of `NewID()`.

In your LINQ To SQL model, navigate to the table's property whose value is auto-generated. Right-click, Properties, and ensure the attribute **Auto Generated Value** is set to True. This will ensure the `INSERT` statement generated doesn't include a value for this table attribute.

[image]

Then you'll be able to access that new property with the default auto-gen value as such:

```
Customer c = new Customer{FirstName="foo"};
db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(c);
db.SubmitChanges();
string someGuid = c.MyGuidField.ToString();
```

Comment: @Roy: thanks. +1 upvote for your good question. Surely lots of others have run into this, and will benefit from your question.