# How to use default NEWID()/NEWSEQUENTIALID() with Guid/uniqueidentifier?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, guid

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SandTable](
    [Id]   [uniqueidentifier]  NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date]              NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SandTable] PRIMARY KEY)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SandTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SandTable_Id]  DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [Id]
```

*Question is not about using NEWID() vs NEWSEQUENTIALID().*

I use linqPad to test the table.

```
SandTables.InsertOnSubmit(new SandTable
{
    // I don't provide any value for Id
    Date = DateTime.Now
});
SubmitChanges();
```

My initial idea was to create an Id column that is able to initialize itself to a value when no Id is provided but will use the id provided when one is provided.

But because Guid is a struct, not a class the Id is never null, Id is initialized to his default value (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`). So SQL server consider that Id has always a value and then the NEWID() default instruction is never called.

Is it possible to force the call to NEWID() on specific value? Should I use a trigger to evaluate the value of Id and when it's (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`) then call NEWID()? What are the solutions or workaround?

Comment: Here is a similar question, interesting but not responding to my specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11974939/196526

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question but if you know you are going to be inserting - why not create the GUID in your code with id=Guid.NewGuid()?  Because you want SQL to create it?

Comment: Also is using a stored procedure for the insert an option? Then you could just check whether the guid was empty and generate a new one if so and perform the insert.

Comment: For compatibility reason because I'm in a situation where we are migrating an application. The old application INSERT new data from non optimized Stored Procedure. I cannot tell you how many version of INSERT we have. The new application use C# code. So the new application can create a Guid but I cannot revise all old query.

Comment: I use Entity Framework in C# code. I prefer to avoid having to use stored procedure. For maintenance reason I would like to keep all logic in C#. (I also simply do not trust my DBA team)

Comment: Does this solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847795/linq-to-sql-handle-newid

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652396/entity-framework-default-values-doesnt-set-in-sql-server-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SandTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_SandTable_Id] DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [Id]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SandTable] 
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_SandTable_Id_Empty] 
    CHECK (
        [Id] <> CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
    )
```

Comment: I believe, Check constraint is used for verifying incoming input. Can you please elaborate on this line : `[Id] <> CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)`

Comment: This would block the insert, I believe he wants it to just generate NewID() IF the passed in id is 0x0 (I could be wrong).

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I'll update with a new answer shortly.

Comment: I confirm with LinqPad shen I insert a first line it work. I get the default Id and then for the next insert I get the classic "SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SandTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SandTable'.
The statement has been terminated." Logic.

Comment: I don't think you're able to do this with a constraint or default value. Triggers are your only option here.

Comment: I have exactly this problem, I don't know why newId() dosent work